# Reference to type IdentityBuilder claims it is defined in microsoft.aspnetcore.identity but it could not be found

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-identity, claims-based-identity

I'm getting this error when upgraded csproj to netstandard1.2 then come NuGet package upgrade in csproj.  This csproj is a dependency DLL to the 3 WebApp csproj.

Error --> Reference to type IdentityBuilder claims it is defined in microsoft.aspnetcore.identity but it could not be found

I'm a bit stump & not having much luck after 2 days of Google search but found this one link at https://forums.asp.net/t/2162412.aspx?Error+with+aspnetcore+3+1+identity+

```
public static void AddPaymentsForPortal<TRequestContext, TUserContext>(this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration, IEnumerable<EmbeddedAssemblySource> embeddedViewAssemblies, PortalRoleType roleType)
{
    services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole<Guid>>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationContext, Guid>()
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
}

public class ApplicationContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole<Guid>, Guid>
{
    public ApplicationContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
    }
}

public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser<Guid>, IUser
{
    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
    {
    }
}

<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore" Version="2.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection" Version="3.1.3" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.AzureStorage" Version="1.0.2" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics" Version="1.1.2" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpOverrides" Version="1.1.2" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity" Version="2.2.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.Xml" Version="1.1.3" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session" Version="1.1.2" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles" Version="1.1.2" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.InMemory" Version="1.1.2" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Redis" Version="1.1.2" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder" Version="3.1.3" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.CommandLine" Version="3.1.3" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Embedded" Version="1.1.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting" Version="3.1.3" />
```

Comment: Hi, any progress on that ? I have kind of the same problem. Thank you.

Comment: @lud - I never made it to work, still.  THen had to put it on the back burner couple of months ago cuz I had to work on other project  :-/

Comment: Arf! Ok, thank you anyway @fletchsod :) Good luck

Answer (score 0):

simply updating all packages solved it for me. here are the steps:

- take a backup of the project...
- open "package manager console" in VS via "view > other windows > package manager console"
- run "Update-Package"